# Sharepoint Online - Disable Versioning, or force onedrive to not clone objects

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning

We reached Sharepoint Online storage limit because of versioning size of non-Office files. OneDrive on Mac (or sharepoint) is just cloning files as revision so e.g. i have a ~400MB file with 40 revisions but storage used by that file is ~13GB!

So i need to fix OneDrive issue to not cloning files (and use storage) or disable versioning which the option is not available on web anymore. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

for OneDrive Versioning there is not OOB way available to disable it.

> Can I disable versioning?
>   With these changes, the document library settings page will no longer support the ability to disable versioning or configure it to retain fewer than one hundred versions. Developer APIs, however, will still allow for setting any custom retention count and disabling versioning, however for the reasons stated above this is highly discouraged.

Reference link:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-OneDrive-Blog/New-Updates-to-OneDrive-and-SharePoint-Team-Site-Versioning/ba-p/204390

You can delete some version history to save some space according to this article:
https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2018/11/11/delete-old-document-versions-from-sharepoint-onedrive/

Note:The way mentioned in the article to disable versioning or set versions less than 100 is not available for now